# В статье "Как создать учётную запись?" стоит упомянуть и другие способы входа

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/creating-accounts

Сейчас там говорится только про FB, Google и SE аккаунты. Стоит добавить информацию о Яндексе и VK.

Ну и да, заодно везде в слове **учетная** заменить **е** на **ё**.

Comment: Поправил, спасибо! Правда, на мой взгляд, текст очень сложный. Было бы здорово его переписать!